# Is there a way to solve the 4Sum problem in better than O(n^3) time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, time-complexity, big-o

Problem: Given an array of n integers and an integer target, are there elements a, b, c, and d in nums such that a + b + c + d = target? Find all unique quadruplets in the array which gives the sum of target.

So there's the obvious n^3 solution with sorting, two nested for loops and then checking.

But is there a way to do better? Note this isn't the decision problem, just see if a solution exists but instead to return *all* unique quadruplets.

Comment: [The first link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-four-elements-that-sum-to-a-given-value-set-2/) when Googling "4 sum" gives an O(n^2 log n) algorithm. [The second link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-four-elements-sum-given-value-set-3-hashmap/) gives an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: "Given an array of integers, find any one combination of four elements in the array whose sum is equal to a given value X." The question I'm asking is for all possible quadruplets, this only finds one

Comment: In the worst case, the number of possible answers may be O(n^3).  So, if you require all possible quadruplets, the answer is "no".

Comment: Yes, consider the case where the input is consecutive integers centered around `target/4`

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to find all unique quadruplets in more efficient way than `O(n^3)` time complexity. But if you want to only count the number of quadruples instead of listing, this can be possible in `O(n^2)` time complexity.

Comment: "it's not possible to find all unique quadruplets in more efficient way than O(n^3) time complexity" - can you elaborate on this? Why isn't it possible? (Can you prove there are O(n^3) **unique** quadruplets?)

Comment: I repeat (from before you moved your comment):  Yes, consider the case where the input is consecutive integers centered around `target/4`

Comment: @comingstorm That's not exactly what I would call a proof.